# NoMethodError: undefined method '' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these models and controller codes:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :receivers_collateral_items, through: :received_trades, source: :wanted_item
 has_many :receivers_wanted_items, through: :received_trades, source: :collateral_item
 has_many :requesters_collateral_items, through: :requested_trades, source: :collateral_item
 has_many :requesters_wanted_items, through: :requested_trades, source: :wanted_item
 validates :year, :price, presence: true, numericality: true
 validates :shares, numericality: 
                     { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, 
                     less_than_or_equal_to: :build_shares }

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :receivers_collateral_items, :receivers_wanted_items, 
                               :requesters_collateral_items, :requesters_wanted_items, 
                               allow_destroy: true
end




class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :trade_recipient, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :wanted_item, class_name: "Item"
 belongs_to :collateral_item, class_name: "Item"
 validates :trade_requester, :trade_recipient, :wanted_item, :collateral_item, presence: true
 validates :shares, numericality: 
                     { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, 
                     less_than_or_equal_to: :max_shares }

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :wanted_item, :collateral_item, allow_destroy: true

 def max_shares
    if wanted_item.shares > collateral_item.shares
        collateral_item.shares
    else
        wanted_item.shares
    end
 end
end


class TradesController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @trade = current_user.requested_trades.build(trade_params)
 end

 private
  def trade_params
   params.require(:trade).permit(:trade_requester_id, :trade_recipient_id, :wanted_item_id, :collateral_item_id, :shares)
  end
end
```

But I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'shares' for nil:NilClass` and a bd rollback.
Steps to reproduce error:

```
t = Trade.new
t.trade_requester_id = User.find(1)
t.trade_recipient_id = User.find(2)
t.wanted_item_id = Item.second
t.collateral_item_id = Item.first
t.shares = 100
t.save
```

The stack trace indicates that it comes from the `numericality` validation in `Trade`, but it seems to me that the class `shares` is being called on *should* exist. I should be able to call `t.wanted_item` and get that item, but instead I get `nil`. `t.wanted_item_id`, however, returns that id. Why is this?

Comment: Provide the steps to repeat the error as code instead of a description.

Comment: @max `t = Trade.new`, `t.trade_requester_id = 1`, `t.trade_recipient_id = 2`, `t.wanted_item_id = 2`, `t.collateral_item_id = 1`, `t.shares = 100`, and then `t.save` which is what actually sets off the no method error

Comment: Add it to the body of the question - not a comment.

Comment: @max okay added

Comment: Just to remove another variable, try commenting out the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: @TomAranda thank you, but that doesn't do anything

Comment: You can try adding `self.` in front of `collatral_item` and `wanted_item` in `max_shares`.  It should not make a difference, but it is worth a try.  I'm grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the new record does is missing a `wanted_item` or a `collateral_item`.  If either of this two associations returns `nil`, then an exception will be thrown.  To fix this use `try` for older versions of Ruby, or the safe navigation operator (`&.`) for Ruby 2.3 or later.

This should solve your issue (pre Ruby 2.3):

```
def max_shares
  if wanted_item.try(:shares).to_i > collateral_item.try(:shares).to_i
    wanted_item.shares
  else
    collateral_item.try(:shares).to_i
  end
end
```

The `try` method will return the value of `wanted_item.shares` and `collateral_item.shares` if they are not `nil`.  If one of them is `nil` then `try` will catch the exception and return `nil`.  The `to_i` converts `nil` to zero.

So `collateral_item.try(:shares).to_i` will return the value of `shares` if `collateral_item` exists, and it will return zero if `collateral_item` is `nil`.

If you are using Ruby 2.3 or later, you should to replace `_item.try(:shares).to_i` with `_item&.shares.to_i`.  The latter is cleaner looking and [faster in execution](https://gist.github.com/hopsoft/ae361319c54bbcb4f8e2).

**Update**

For replication, be sure you are assigning records to your associations and not to their ids:

```
t = Trade.new
t.trade_requester = User.find(1)
t.trade_recipient = User.find(2)
t.wanted_item = Item.second
t.collateral_item = Item.first
t.shares = 100
t.save!
```

Comment: what is the point of using`try` when the only thing it does is suppress the stack trace? a `Trade` won't save to the db unless everything is validated. what i'm trying to figure out is *why* those `Items` are `nil`.

Comment: Good question.  It could be because users with those ids do not exist.  What do `t.wanted_item` and `t.collateral_item` return before `t.save`?

Comment: when i check the record I'm trying to save with `t`, I get `#<Trade id: nil, trade_requester_id: 1, trade_recipient_id: 2, wanted_item_id: 2, collateral_item_id: 1, approved: nil, shares: 100>`. which is expected. but then when I check `t.wanted_item_id` or `t.collateral_item_id`, I get `nil`. which is unexpected

Comment: Try setting your associations this way: `t.trade_requester = User.find(1)` and make sure `User.find(1)` returns a record.

Comment: That works in the console. `t.wanted_item` is no longer `nil`, but I still have the same problem: I'm still getting `NoMethodError (undefined method 'shares' for nil:NilClass)` when using `:max_shares` in the validations (I need that validation on shares because the max number that can be traded must be equal to the `Item` with the smallest number of available shares).

Comment: Do `t.collateral_item` and `t.wanted_item` return something other than `nil`?  Also, do `Item.first` and `Item.second` return a non-`nil` value?  Finally, make sure `id` is not part of the assignment.  Example: the assignment should be `t.collateral_item = Item.first`

Comment: `t.wanted_item` and `t.collateral_item` both return the appropriate `Item`. I only get the `undefined method 'shares' for nil:NilClass` error when the numericality validation makes a call to `max_shares`. `shares` is suddenly not defined on those objects.